# for-of loop in Angular

Tags: angular, foreach, for-of-loop

Is there an easier way to use `for-of` loop in Angular 9?
I had written code like this:

```
Object.keys(httpParams).forEach((key) => {
  for (const paramKey of httpParams[key]) {
     params = params.append(key, paramKey);
  }
});
```

But are there some other ways not to use this `for-of` loop

Comment: what is params here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.entries(httpParams).forEach((data) => {
     let key = data[0];
     data[1].forEach((item)=> {
            params=params.append(key, item);
     });
});
```